# Doctrine ORM - SQLSTATE [22001, 0]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine

I am using Doctrine ORM (v 2.11.1) with SQL Server and I get the following error when creating a new record with a column value of more than 4000 characters:

`An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE [22001, 0]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation`

The column is varchar(max), running an insert via SQL directly works fine.
It works fine also when updating the record with Doctrine with a value longer than 4000 characters.

Changing the column type from varchar(max) to varchar(5000) (or any other number) does not solve the issue. The same happens with nvarchar(max) or nvarchar(*any length*)

Comment: What versions of PHP and php_sqlsrv/php_pdo_sqlsrv are you using? The following bug report suggests that there was an issue at some point with msphpsql prior to v5.10 beta2... [Error "String data, right truncation" when reusing the same prepared statemnt many times under PHP 8.1 with pdo_sqlsrv 5.10 beta1 #1329](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1329)

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning, it turned out the problem was caused by php sqlsrv. I had version 5.10.0 installed and updating to 5.11.0 solved the issue.